# case insensitive validated enum conversion with TypeConverter

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, case-insensitive

With Enum.Parse I can ignore case:

```
var result = (EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), input, ignoreCase:true)
```

But when I use a TypeConverter, it fails unless my string exactly matches the enum:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(EnumType));
if (converter.IsValid(first))
{
    var result = (EnumType)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
}
```

Is there a way to make TypeConverter IsValid case insensitive, Or will I just have to use exception based programming here? I couldn't see anything on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I am trying to make a generic way of converting string input into a desired type, so I want to use TypeConverter.

Comment: I think the `ConvertFromString` method is Case-insensitive by default?

Comment: Your code  converts case insensitive. Or you wanted to make it case sensitive?

Comment: ah right, I was using converter.IsValid to avoid exception handling, which is case sensitive